# consul docker failed to persist data after docker is killed

Tags: docker, consul, consul-kv

I am using consul docker to save my key/value pair, this is the command I am using to start docker:

```
 docker run -d --name=dev-consul -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0  
-p 8500:8500 
-v /Users/user1/projects/consul/consul_volumn/data:/consul/data  consul
```

But after I killed the docker instance and re-run this command, all the previously saved data in consul are gone.

I checked the doc and saw the volumn exposed is /consul/data, that is why I am mounting my local file system to the docker instance. But why data is still now persisted here?

Hope to hear your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Fixed by adding this command:

```
agent -server -ui -bind 0.0.0.0 -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap -bootstrap-expect 1
```

Try running:

```
docker run -d --name=dev-consul -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 -p 8500:8500 -v /Users/user1/projects/consul/consul_volumn/data:/consul/data consul agent -server -ui -bind 0.0.0.0 -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap -bootstrap-expect 1
```